# Rows Concatenated Upon Import

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to import a csv into my MySQL table, however when importing, the first row is imported, and then it concatenates all the next rows onto the last column.

Using the following SQL

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/baambiance.csv'
INTO TABLE BusinessAttributes
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(business_id, name, value)
```

With the following example CSV (sorry don't know how to copy/paste a table)

[image]

and it results in this as the value column

"{romantic: false, intimate: false, classy: false, hipster: false, divey: false, touristy: false, trendy: false, upscale: false, casual: true}"
 agVP2LxAVHyqmhxEHnpg,Ambience,"{romantic: false, intimate: false, classy: false, hipster: false, divey: false, touristy: false, trendy: false, upscale: false, casual: false}"

Comment: It sounds like the lines my not be terminated by a newline. Try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` or `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`.

Comment: @kmoser that was it! Would you mind making that an answer post so I can mark the question solved and credit you appropriately.

Comment: Please see my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the lines my not be terminated by a newline. Try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` or `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`.